# Python ssl get ciphers supported

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, tls1.2, pyopenssl

I was wondering why isn't there a simple way to find the ciphers supported by a particular ssl context? (Or did I miss it)

I know we can use `socket.cipher()` to get the one being used for the connection for that particular `socket`, but why not something to get all supported ciphers?

Another things is,

I have a server which is running openssl library with the cipher string `"HIGH+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!SHA1"`. The client is a python file using the `ssl` library, with default options, and after the connection is established the `socket.cipher()` shows the below tuple

```
('DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
```

How is the connection established with TLSv1, when I explicitly mentioned TLSv1.2, and how is it using `SHA384`, when TLSv1 doesn't have support for anything higher then `SHA1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering why isn't there a simple way to find the ciphers supported by a particular ssl context? (Or did I miss it)

Only OpenSSL 1.1.0 added a function SSL_CTX_get_ciphers to access this list and this functionality is not yet available in Python.

> ```
> ('DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
> ```
>
> How is the connection established with TLSv1, when I explicitly mentioned TLSv1.2, and how is it using SHA384, when TLSv1 doesn't have support for anything higher then SHA1?

According to [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_ssl.c#L1556) Python is using SSL_CIPHER_get_version to find out the version string. The matching [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CIPHER_get_version.html) says for OpenSSL 1.0.2:

> SSL_CIPHER_get_version() returns string which indicates the SSL/TLS protocol version that first defined the cipher. **This is currently SSLv2 or TLSv1/SSLv3. In some cases it should possibly return "TLSv1.2" but does not**; use SSL_CIPHER_description()

Thus it is a bug in OpenSSL which according to the documentation of the same function in OpenSSL 1.1.0 was fixed in the latest OpenSSL version.

Comment: So, (If I have understood correctly) I would need to use a higher version of Python (which would in turn use the latest OpenSSL version), to make this work? Are there any workaround to make this work?

Comment: @Haris: yes, this should be fixed when using a Python compiled against a newer OpenSSL version. As a workaround you might create your own mapping based on the output of `openssl ciphers -V 'ALL'`.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing. Since the tuple returned shows SHA384 is being used, can this be taken as a sign that for sure a TLS version higher then TLSv1 is being used? Does any other version lower then TLSv1.2 has SHA256 and higher mac cipher support?

Comment: @Haris: SHA256 and higher is only available with TLS 1.2. But if you want to know the TLS protocol version actually used in the connection you should not look at the version part of the cipher which should only show the minimal TLS version required to use the cipher. Instead you should call `socket.version()`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That works like a charm. I can see now that TLSv1.2 is being used. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[`SSLContext.get_ciphers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.get_ciphers) was added in Python 3.4.

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  2 2023, 13:45:54) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(ssl.create_default_context().get_ciphers()[0])
{'aead': True,
 'alg_bits': 256,
 'auth': 'auth-any',
 'description': 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   '
                'Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD',
 'digest': None,
 'id': 50336514,
 'kea': 'kx-any',
 'name': 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
 'protocol': 'TLSv1.3',
 'strength_bits': 256,
 'symmetric': 'aes-256-gcm'}
>>> pprint(sorted([cipher['name'] for cipher in ssl.create_default_context().get_ciphers()]))
['DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
 'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256',
 'DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256',
 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256',
 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384',
 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256',
 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384',
 'ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
 'TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256']
>>>
```